# How to pass data between two components in angularjs syntax es6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I would like to pass data from the todos component to the todo component and display all elements in the form of a list.
I download data from the service and place it in the `todos.controller`. In `todos.component`, I use `bindings: {todos: '<'}`. In the `todos.html` view, it provides data in the form of `todos = $ ctrl.todos`. In `todo.html`, it iterates over `todos` and wants to return `todo.name`. Effect: returns only `'Todo'`.

**todo.service.js**

```
export class TodoService {
  constructor($http) {
  'ngInject';
   this.$http = $http;
 }
  getTodos() {
    return this.$http.get('/api/todos');
  }
}
```

**todos.controller.js**

```
class TodosController {
   constructor(TodoService) {
    'ngInject'
    this.TodoService = TodoService;
   }

    $onInit() {
      this.todos = null;
      this.TodoService.getTodos().then(response => 
        {
           this.todos = response.data;
           console.log(this.todos);
        });

    }
}

export default TodosController;
```

**todo.component.js**

```
import template from './todo.html';
import controller from './todo.controller';
import './todo.scss';

let todoComponent = {
  bindings: {
    todos: '<'
  },
  template,
  controller
};`

export default todoComponent;
```

**todos.html**

```
<h1>Todos</h1>
<ul>
    <todo todos="$ctrl.todos"></todo>
</ul>
```

**todo.html**

```
<div>
    <p ng-repeat='todo in $ctrl.todos track by $index'>Todo: 
     {{$ctrl.todo.name}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use capital letters in component names in HTML. Also in HTML5 the slash is an error except on pre-HTML5 void elements. Error recovery will cause browsers to ignore it and treat the tag as a regular start tag. This often ends up with a missing end tag causing subsequent elements to be children instead of siblings.

Comment: I changed  `<Todo todos="$ctrl.todos" / >` on  `<todo todos="$ctrl.todos" ></todo>` but it doesn't work

Comment: Which version of angularjs are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **`todo.html`** as follows:

```
<div>
    <p ng-repeat='todo in $ctrl.todos'>Todo: 
     ̶{̶{̶$̶c̶t̶r̶l̶.̶t̶o̶d̶o̶.̶n̶a̶m̶e̶}̶}̶
     {{todo.name}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Also with **`todos.html`**:

```
<h1>Todos</h1>
̶<̶u̶l̶>̶
    <todo todos="$ctrl.todos"></todo>
̶<̶/̶u̶l̶>̶
```

The only permitted content of `<ul>` elements is zero or more `<li>` elements.

For more information, see

- [MDN HTML Reference - `<ul>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)